Try to send email attaching file with gmail and Flutter
I am trying to send an attached file with gmail but i'm always getting the error :
"unable to attach file" from gmail App
I'm using flutter_email_sender package to send an email with an attached file.
It work fine with outlook application but not with gmail.
But when i edit the mail (adding a character in the body) gmail send the mail with the attached file and i don't unterstand why i need to edit my email body to send the attached file.
here's my code :
// create a temporary file
String directoryPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
String fileName = generateFileName();
File csvFile = await File('$directoryPath/$fileName').writeAsString(csv);

final Email email = Email(
  subject: 'subject',
  attachmentPaths: [csvFile.absolute.path],
);

// send email
await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);

// delete the temporary file
if (await csvFile.exists()) {
  await csvFile.delete();
}

I already try seting body in the mail but the result in the same, i need to edit the body with gmail for the file to be sent without error.
I just want to send an attached file with gmail without editing anything in the gmail App.

if it works with the Outlook App, then I suspect this is a security "feature" from gmail. Try to understand how the flutter_email_sender works and then google if gmail is known to have a limitation on what they are doing.

I am facing the same issue while I am working with only one E-mail Provider
i change the plugin to  flutter_email_sender and it is work for me
final Email email = Email(
  body: 'Email body',
  subject: 'Email subject',
  recipients: ['example@example.com'],
  cc: ['cc@example.com'],
  bcc: ['bcc@example.com'],
  attachmentPaths: ['/path/to/attachment.zip'],
  isHTML: false,
);

await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);

